# How to change connection to the database on acts as taggable on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, acts-as-taggable-on

I have used rails and gem(acts as taggable on).
I want to change acts as taggable on's database setting.
so,I set as below

-database.yml

```
default: &default
    adapter: mysql2
    database: my_db1
    host: localhost
    username: root
    password: pass

development:
    <<: *default

my_db2:
    <<: *default
    database: my_db2
```

-user_model.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_taggable
    establish_connection :my_db2
end
```

and, execute as below

```
User.find(1)
//this line result is connection to my_db2


User.find(1).tag_list
//this line result is connection to my_db1
//i want to connect to my_db2 in this code(by acts as taggable on)
```

I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: tag_list is a different table, that table doesn't have a config to tell rails to use db_2

Comment: Thanks to response. sorry, I knew it. but I want to resolve this problem somehow or another. Even if I use Monkey Patch. Thanks

Comment: what does this return `User.find(1).tag_list.first.class` ?

Comment: ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.4ms) . So I want to apply code which (establish_connection: my_db2) to ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag . Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok so you need to override the tags class, try creating a file called `tags.rb` inside your `config/initializers` folder and then add this

```
module ActsAsTaggableOn
  class Tag
    establish_connection :my_db2
  end
end
```

Restart your server and then it should work.

Comment: if the problem is solved please mark the answer by clicking the check mark, if you needed to modify my answer to get it to work tell me so i could correct my answer for future readers.

Comment: OK. In my environment, i resolve this problem just set your code at "config/initializers"

Comment: make sure if you want the entirety of your acts-as-taggable-on setup to be on a different db that you also override the Tagging class.

Answer (score 1):

I also had to add the Tagging class to Mohammed's answer.

```
module ActsAsTaggableOn
  class Tag
    establish_connection :my_db2
  end
  class Tagging
    establish_connection :my_db2
  end
end
```